# Packet filter syntax and loopback

Tags: macos, networking, tcpdump, libpcap, loopback

I have a **tun** adapter (OS X) which looks like this:

```
tun11: flags=8851<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.12.0.2 --> 10.12.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    open (pid 4004)
```

I send a UDP packet to it:

```
echo "lol" | nc -4u 10.12.0.1 8000
```

and able to see it with **tcpdump**:

```
➜  build git:(master) ✗ sudo tcpdump -i tun11 -vv
tcpdump: listening on tun11, link-type NULL (BSD loopback), capture     size 262144 bytes
14:39:16.669055 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21714, offset 0, flags     [none], proto UDP (17), length 32)
    10.12.0.2.55707 > 10.12.0.1.irdmi: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 4
```

However I do not see anything when I use capture filter:

```
➜  build git:(master) ✗ sudo tcpdump -i tun11 udp -vv
tcpdump: listening on tun11, link-type NULL (BSD loopback), capture size 262144 bytes
```

Same syntax works fine with ethernet adapter:

```
➜  build git:(master) ✗ sudo tcpdump -i en0 udp -vv
tcpdump: listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:42:15.010329 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 7539, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 291)
    xxxx.54915 > 10.64.3.255.54915: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 263
```

I checked man **pcap-filter** and found an interesting sentence related to capture filters:

```
Note that this primitive does not chase the protocol header chain.
```

Is it related to my problem? Anyway, why capture filters (at least protocol part) do not work for loopback adapters and is there way to make them work?

**Addition**

Interesting, it works with tun device created by OpenVPN. But I do not understand what is the difference.

```
tun11: flags=8851<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.12.0.2 --> 10.12.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    open (pid 5792)
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 198.18.1.214 --> 198.18.1.213 netmask 0xffffffff 
    inet6 xxxx%utun0 prefixlen 64 optimistic scopeid 0xa 
    inet6 xxxx::1074 prefixlen 64 tentative 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
```

Comment: Have you tried the protochain primitive? I only ask because of the odd sounding sentence you mention about chasing the chain (whatever that means)...:  "protochain protocol: True if the packet is an IPv4 or IPv6 packet of protocol type protocol.  Note that this primitive chases the protocol header chain."

Comment: tried `protochain \\udp`, same thing